# Make all branches merge new changes from a devel/hotfix branch

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have a few feature/topic branches `A`,`B`,`C`. And I have a `devel` branch.

I have just finished a patch/hotfix and committed it to `devel`. `A`,`B`,`C` *were* all child-branches of `devel` *until a while ago*, but now they lack the patch/hotfix that I just committed to `devel`.

How do I make all the branches `A`,`B`,`C` to merge the new changes (patch/hotfix) from the (*new*-)`devel`?

I could go to each branch and then merge `devel` into each branch one by one, but I guess there would be a better way?

edit: `devel`, not <strike>`master`</strike>

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update each branch one at a time. You could write a script to do this if you really wanted to, but that doesn't change the fact that they all need to be updated.

Either

```
git checkout A
git merge devel
```

or

```
git checkout A
git rebase devel
```

for each of your branches. [Some discussion on merge vs rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge).